# VBA, Overflow error trying to copy previous column

Tags: excel, vba

I have this piece of code where I am trying to copy the previous column based on a string in my `Sheets("Input").Range("A2")` , Then input in the cell is `Y1M7`

However I am getting `Overflow` error. Can someone help ?

```
Sub NewFind()

Dim nameColumn As Long

With Sheets("Load check data")

    
    nameColumn = .Rows(1).Find(Sheets("Input").Range("A2"), .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole).Column

    .Range(.Cells(2, nameColumn - 1), .Cells(k, nameColumn - 1)).Copy

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: When you use `Find` on a range (`.Rows(1)` in this case), the range you specify for `After` must be in the range `Find` is searching.  Your code is trying to specify the bottom right cell on the sheet, which clearly is not in row 1.  Replace `.Cells(.Cells.Count)` with `.Rows(1).Cells(.Rows(1).Cells.Count)`

Comment: Other points: 1) you should assign the Find to a range variable and test it for `Nothing` before trying to get its Column. 2) If you were actually trying to get the Bottom Right cell you would need `.Cells(.Cells.CountLarge)` since since `.Cells.Count` for a whole sheet overflows a Long

Comment: You are getting the overflow error because the value being returned by `.Cells.Count` is greater than the limits for the `Long` data type. Long Data type max is `2,147,483,647` but there are `17,179,869,184` cells in a worksheet.  If you need to return that value, use `Cells.CountLarge`